# Multiple instances of a field, differently formatted - how?

Tags: 7, entities

And if I wanted a particular field displayed on a node twice, but each instance built with a different formatter - what should I do?
Example: a term reference field - formatted as plain text at the top, and as a link - at the bottom of a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a render a field with a named formatter you can use [`field_view_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7) with an array of display settings:

```
$display_settings = array(
  'label' => 'inline', // Position of label; 'inline', 'above' or 'hidden'
  'type' => 'link', // Name of the formatter,
  'settings' => array(/* Array of settings for the formatter based on your requirements */)
);

print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name', $display_settings));
```

Comment: I notice that field_view_field docs say don't use in a template file. Is that what you're suggesting in your code snippet above? If not, is there a another way to render a field with display setting in a node template file? Happy to ask another question on DS if more appropriate.

Comment: Yes Dave you _should_ do this in a preprocess function, add a variable to the $contents array and render it. But it will work in the Node template too, just not ideal.

Answer (score 5):

I would use Panels. You can add each field as many times as you want and pick a different formatter every time.

1. Install the [Chaos tool suite (ctools)](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module, and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).
2. Enable the Page Manager and Panels.
3. Enable the node template
4. Create a variant of type "Panel".
5. Pick a suitable layout.
6. Go to the "Selection rules" settings and add a "Node:type" setting so this is used for a single node type.
7. Add your fields and select your formatters.
8. Save

Using Panels requires a bit of understanding of the tools it provides. There are a few videos [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager).